# Insert function is not working due to value Error

Tags: python, methods, insert

```
x,y,z=input("enter dimmensions:").split(",")

x,y,z=int(x),int(y),int(z)
a=[]
for i in range(0,x):
    b=[]
    for j in range(0,y):
        c=[]
        for k in range(0,z):
            c.insert(int(input(f"location[{i}][{j}]:"),int(input("enter item:")))) 
        b.insert(int(input(f"Location[{i}]")),c)
    a.insert(int(input(f"Location")),b)
print(f"Here is your fully customized:\n{a}")
```

I am writing a code to create a customized 3D list:

```
c.insert(int(input(f"location[{i}][{j}]:"),int(input("enter item:"))))

ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0
```

As you can see after I put in the item for the inner most list and press enter this error is shown.

Comment: What is `c` and what did you type to get the error?

Comment: What is the text you are writing? For the inputs? That's what's breaking.

Comment: refresh the page

Comment: You haven't told us what you type when the code is asking for your entries. Without this, we can't figure out where you made a mistake.

Comment: just a number such as 3 or 45

Comment: when it prompts "enter item"

Comment: the very first time itself after entering the location for the item of the inner most list when i enter any no. for the insert method to put into the empty list

Answer (score 0):

`c.insert(int(input(f"location[{i}][{j}]:"),int(input("enter item:"))))` is indeed the problem, because the parentheses are wrong.

Try `c.insert(int(input(f"location[{i}][{j}]:")), int(input("enter item:")))`, otherwise the first `int` has an extra integer argument that is probably wrong (it's the base that is used to parse the input string, as explained by the error message).

Comment: oh my god completely forgot to check the no. of parathesis

Comment: No pb, wasn't the first thing I looked at either.

Comment: Seems like it, but you don't have any protection against bad inputs (if they are not integers).

Comment: this is intended for integers only so no issue